# Automtically creating new redirects and alias on node_save

Tags: nodes, database

Here is the code I'm using to change the name field of my nodes if they contain certain phrases.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'my_product')
    ->fieldCondition('field_my_name', 'value', 'Old Phrase%', 'LIKE');

foreach ($result['node'] as $key => $value) {
    $node = node_load($key);
    $node->field_my_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = str_replace('Old Phrase', 'New Phrase', $node->field_my_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
    node_save($node);
}
```

It successfully changes the name; however, I'd like to automatically create a new URL and also a redirect entry from the old URL to the newly generated one.

I have `pathauto` installed and my URL Alias is configured to use the `my_name` field, but the code above does not change the Alias.

Answer (score 1):

Pathauto should automatically create a new alias with the updates (unless you have it turned off on the node). pathauto.module lines 519-522:

```
// Skip processing if the user has disabled pathauto for the node.
if (isset($node->path['pathauto']) && empty($node->path['pathauto'])) {
  return;
}
```

The [Global Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) can then provide 301 redirects to the new URL alias.